# Rails 3 and AWS::S3 Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am following the documentation (http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) to try to begin working on S3 into my application (for serving files to the end user) but I keep running into errors.

Here is my Model:

```
class File < AWS::S3::S3Object
  set_current_bucket_to 'test-bucket'
end
```

This is what I am trying via the Rails Console:

```
File.find 'test.pdf'
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `find' for File:Class
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here... anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File is not a very good name for your model as it gets overwrited by Ruby's standart class File ([docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html)). Just choose another name and everything will just work!

Comment: DOH! Definitely need more coffee... :( Thanks for the help!